# explode não funcionando certamente?

Tags: php

Tenho uma variável que vai buscar uma `string` à base de dados.

Eu uso `explode` para dividir a string e transformar num `array`, para mais tarde serem apresentados.

No entanto, quando uso um `for`, ele fica infinito.

Eis o meu código.

Exemplo da string: `$string="array.jpg,teste.pdf,word.docx"`

```
$count=explode(",", $string);
for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++){ 
   echo $count[$i];
}
```

Comment: `$i<=$count`, você está comparando um número inteiro com um *array*. Não faltou a função `count()` aí, não? Cogite utilizar a estrutura `foreach`, também; deve simplificar o código.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Eu tinha essa função mas não a consegui implementar também. Poderia me ajudar a implementar?

Comment: a sua variavel count esta recebendo o resultado do explode da string, não o tamanho do explode, com isso o for não vai funcionar corretamente. de uma olhada nessa url, ela explica bem a logica de um for em uma variavel que recebe um array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502748/php-count-the-number-of-strings-after-exploded

Comment: Usa um `foreach` mesmo. Assim não precisa contar nem calcular o número de lementos do array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro do seu `for`, você está comparando um valor inteiro, `$i`, com um *array*, `$count`, e o PHP acha que fazer essa comparação é algo bem normal e não reclama disso, mas se você pnsar bem, não faz sentido. Você precisa comparar dois valores inteiros e, como o segundo aparentemente deveria ser o tamanho do *array*, obter esse segundo valor com `count($count)`:

```
<?php

$string="array.jpg,teste.pdf,word.docx";
$count=explode(",", $string);

for($i = 0; $i < count($count); $i++){ 
   echo $count[$i];
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/kaE3dY) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/MatureUnsteadyGreendarnerdragonfly)</sup>

> Perceba que também alterei o operador de `<=` para `<`, pois a indexação do *array* começa em zero e vai até `n-1`, não existindo o valor em `n`.

Mas o mesmo resultado pode ser obtido com o `foreach`:

```
<?php

$string="array.jpg,teste.pdf,word.docx";
$count=explode(",", $string);

foreach($count as $arquivo){ 
   echo $arquivo;
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/EfvgzF) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/InsidiousFrozenBronco)</sup>

Comment: `<=` foi um erro que eu tenho frequentemente por distração, porque eu tenho o vício de começar sempre valores em `0`. Muito obrigado pela ajuda, darei a sua resposta como aceite em breve! Além disso, nunca pensei que o `foreach` fosse tão fácil de usar!